# is it ok to construct from a stl container which has a different allocator?

Tags: c++, stl, allocation, xeon-phi, cilk-plus

Say I have

```
std::vector<T, allocator1=default allocator in STL>  A

std::vector<T, allocator2=some other allocator> B
```

I am using __offload::shared_allocator as allocator2 in Cilk Plus for offloading from Host CPU to Xeon Phi coprocessor

Can I construct A from B?

```
std::vector<T> A{B.begin(), B.end()};
```

And more general, for which kind of STL functions that different allocators will matter?

Comment: That's not a copy constructor you are calling.

Comment: Ok sorry...I will change the title

Comment: As long as they aren't trivial pointers, isn't `std::vector<T, std::allocator<T>>::iterator` a different type than `std::vector<T, __offload::shared_allocator<T>>::iterator`?

Comment: @nabijaczleweli Doesn't matter (and they need not be, if the iterator is SCARY), the two-iterator constructor accepts all input iterators.

Comment: @T.C. Just looked it up, you are right. I'm an idiot/was thinking about something else, sorry.

Comment: Careful: There are two very different ideas here. Different allocator *types*, like `vector<int, A>` and `vector<int, B>`, and different *allocators* (of the same type), like `vector<int, A> v1, v2; v1.get_allocator() == v2.get_allocator();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the constructor

```
std::vector<T> A{B.begin(), B.end()};
```

should work fine since it works for any two iterators.  As for the question "for which kind of STL functions that different allocators will matter?", there's two kinds of "different":

1. Allocators with different types.
2. Allocators with the same type, but compare as different.

For incompatibilities with respect to (1), you should see a compile-time error because the type system will catch it.  For (2), I don't know if STL implementations catch the possible problems or not.  The primary container/function to worry about in that regard are the `splice` methods on class `list` (and `splice_after` methods on class `forward_list`), because they move an object allocated in one container to another container.  As footnote 265 of the C++11 standard notes, the STL containers require that allocators compare equal, so such movement should not be a problem.

With respect to offload issues, if A is allocated with a plain STL allocator, then it cannot be constructed on the host side and used on the coprocessor side.  But B can be used on both sides.  Here is an example that constructs B `using an`offload::shared_allocator`, and constructs`A` from it on the coprocessor side.

```
#pragma offload_attribute (push, _Cilk_shared)
#include <vector>
#include "offload.h"
#include <cstdio>
#pragma offload_attribute (pop)

_Cilk_shared std::vector<int, __offload::shared_allocator<int> > B;

_Cilk_shared void foo() {
#ifdef __MIC__
    std::vector<int> A(B.begin(),B.end());
    for( auto& x: A )
        std::printf("%d\n", x);
#else
    std::printf("Host\n");
#endif
}

int main() {
    auto y = 1;
    for( int i=0; i<10; ++i ) {
        B.push_back(y);
        y *= 10;
    }
    _Cilk_offload foo();
}
```

It should print:

```
1
10
100
1000
10000
100000
1000000
10000000
100000000
1000000000
```

Comment: So, from just a C++ point of view, everything is fine. But from an Intel Xeon Phi coprocessor point of view - you are using B in an offload region but what about A? I have a lot to learn about using C++ with offload code, so I could be all wet, but I don't believe A can be used in an offload region and the first time you used the allocator in A, won't you mess up B as far as using it in offloaded code is concerned?

Comment: But if A is constructed on the coprocessor and you insert an element into A, what will happen if you iterate over B on the host side? Won't it send you off into the weeds?

Comment: A was constructed with a copy of the elements in B.  Changing A has no effect on B, and vice versa after construction of A.

Comment: Basically I can not move construct new object if they have different allocator right?